# Send a POST request to a OAuth Org app with a constant url. Possible?

Tags: apex, api

I have a non-salesforce application that needs to send POST requests to my org. From a [blog post](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com) by Salesforce, there is much talk of having to do back and forth redirects on the webpage till you get the access token and I presume a refresh token.

My problem, the non-salesforce app is only asking for a POST url to send the requests to. There is no way to code in the authorization steps that I'm aware of. In addition, there is no way to store a token or refresh token in my non-salesforce app. All there is is a field to save a POST url.

Is it possible to create a HTTP POST url to a salesforce org that uses OAuth that never needs to change?

Comment: @Eric I need it to be secure though.

Comment: @TylerZika How are you going to secure the the API if you don't perform any authorization? Maybe you could check the [RestRequest.remoteAddress](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_restrequest.htm#apex_methods_system_restrequest) is a known value? I'd still be hesitant to call it secure on that alone.

Comment: @DanielBallinger I guess, is it possible to secure once?

Comment: What do you mean by secure once? That is kind of what the OAuth Refresh token is for. I did have one idea that you could include the refresh token in the POST body and then have Apex complete the OAuth process.